# I am trying to put a round system in my game and i don't know why it isn't working

Tags: python, pygame

```
spawned = False     #Global Variable
def timer(clockTime,forwardTime,spawned):
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= forwardTime:
        forwardTime = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 600
        clockTime += 1
    if clockTime ==21:
        bird.rounds += 1
        clockTime = 0
        spawned = False
        print(spawned)
    return clockTime,forwardTime,spawned

def Rounds(spawned):
    if bird.rounds ==1 and spawned == False:    
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob])
        spawned ==True
        print(spawned)
    elif bird.rounds ==2 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(100,200))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2])
        spawned == True
    elif bird.rounds ==3 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==4 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==5 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==6 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob6 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        blob6.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==7 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob6 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob7 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        blob6.target=bird
        blob7.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==8 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob6 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob7 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob8 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        blob6.target=bird
        blob7.target=bird
        blob8.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==9 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob6 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob7 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob8 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob9 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        blob6.target=bird
        blob7.target=bird
        blob8.target=bird
        blob9.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8,blob9])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8,blob9])
        spawned ==True
    elif bird.rounds ==10 and spawned ==False:
        blob = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob2 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob3 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob4 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob5 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob6 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob7 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob8 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob9 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob10 = Enemy(random.randint(200,1000),random.randint(200,300))
        blob.target=bird
        blob2.target=bird
        blob3.target=bird
        blob4.target=bird
        blob5.target=bird
        blob6.target=bird
        blob7.target=bird
        blob8.target=bird
        blob9.target=bird
        blob10.target=bird
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8,blob9,blob10])
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob,blob2,blob3,blob4,blob5,blob6,blob7,blob8,blob9,blob10])
        spawned ==True
    return all_sprites,enemies,spawned

pygame.init()                               # Pygame is initialised (starts running)

players = pygame.sprite.Group()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1250,850]) # Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")       # Name your window
background_image = pygame.image.load("untilted.png")

done = False                                # Loop until the user clicks the close button.

clock = pygame.time.Clock()                 # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
black    = (   0,   0,   0)                 # Define some colors using rgb values.  These can be
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)                 # used throughout the game instead of using rgb values.
font = pygame.font.Font(None,36)
# Define additional Functions and Procedures here
score = 0
bird = Character()
rounds = 0
clockTime = 0
forwardTime = 0
bullet = Bullet(pygame.mouse.get_pos(),[bird.rect.x,bird.rect.y])

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done == False:


    for event in pygame.event.get():        # Check for an event (mouse click, key press)
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:       # If user clicked close window
            done = True                     # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        elif key[pygame.K_e]:
            bullet = Bullet(pygame.mouse.get_pos(),[bird.rect.x,bird.rect.y])
            bullet.rect.x = bird.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = bird.rect.y
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    clockTime,forwardTime,spawned = timer(clockTime,forwardTime,spawned)
    all_sprites,enemies,spawned = Rounds(spawned)
    all_sprites.update(enemies)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    textImg = font.render("Score: " + str(bird.score),1,white)
    textImg2 = font.render("Lives: " + str(bird.heart),1,white)
    textImg3 = font.render("Round: " + str(bird.rounds),1,white)
    textImg4 = font.render("clock " + str(clockTime),1,white)
    screen.blit(textImg,(10,10))
    screen.blit(textImg2,(150,10))
    screen.blit(textImg3,(300,10))
    screen.blit(textImg4,(700,10))
    pygame.display.update()                   # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.

    clock.tick(20)                              # Limit to 20 frames per second
    if bird.heart == 0:
        pygame.quit()

    pygame.quit()
```

When I run the code, it spawns the enemy every second instead of just spawning it when the round ends, so when I run it, the enemies coordinates repeatedly change, but when it hits the next round it does spawn the enemy, but then that enemies coordinates are randomized every second like the other ones.

Comment: And your question is? Nobody is going to go through this much code, reduce it to a minimal example!

Comment: I am asking what is wrong with my code, and how to fix it

Comment: So many things going wrong in this script... Like `spawned == True` is a comparison and doesn't do anything at that place. Another example would be this: `done == False`. For me this is just bad style. You should write it like `not done`. The `pygame.quit()` also makes no sense because you're calling it on every loop step...

Comment: Short code review: consider making your enemies in `Rounds()` in a loop.  On each round #, you create that many enemies.  `Loop <roundNumber> times: createEnemy(): End Loop`

Comment: Your `Rounds` function is actually very ugly. Why don't you check first if spawned is False like `if not spawned: return`?

Answer (score 0):

`spawned` is always false.  It's meant as your control for slowing the creation of enemies, but you never set it to true.

This tests equality and returns:

```
spawned ==True
```

You want

```
spawned = True
```

Comment: ok, so i have implemented that in, and i have also defined the all_sprites and the enemies, but now its giving me:

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: Glad to hear this solved the question at hand!  To figure out the AttributeError, you should start by looking into the 'list' object the stack trace is referring to and check out the API for it on Google.  Python has awesome docs for their API calls.  Perhaps there's a method other than 'update' to do what you need.